# AutoMapper CreateMap MemberList.None option still tries to bind destination properties

Tags: .net, automapper

I have the mapping defined like below. On copying a DB entity to DTO where MemberList.None is used in mapping, Automapper still tries to map a destination property called StaffProperties. Is it not suppose to use the explicit mapping and ignore other properties in destination object?

AutoMapper version: 12.0.1

## Mapping

```
    CreateMap<Staff, StaffDetailDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.StaffProperties, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StaffProperties>(src.Properties)));

    CreateMap<StaffRole, StaffDetailDto>(MemberList.None)
        .ForMember(dest => dest.OrganizationRole, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) =>
        {
            return (src != null) ? src.OrganizationRole : (OrganizationRole?)null;
        }));
```

## Service layer

```
    var staffDetailDto = _mapper.Map<StaffDetailDto>(stf);

    // fetch staffRole from db

    staffDetailDto = _mapper.Map(staffRole, staffDetailDto);
```

throws exception on _mapper.Map(staffRole, staffDetailDto)

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
StaffRole -> StaffDetailDto
Baseline.Models.StaffRole -> Baseline.Services.Models.Staff.StaffDetailDto

Type Map configuration:
StaffRole -> StaffDetailDto
Baseline.Models.StaffRole -> Baseline.Services.Models.Staff.StaffDetailDto

Destination Member:
StaffProperties
```

Comment: Replace `ForAllOtherMembers` with a type converter.

Comment: I'm not using ForAllOtherMembers() as it has been deprecated since 11.0

Comment: Obviously :) But the way to do explicit mapping is a type converter.

Comment: I'm not familiar. Do you have a pointer to sample code? Thx

Answer (score -1):

I ended up avoiding MemberList.None and as a substitute for ForAllOtherMembers () created an extension method IgnoreAllNonExisting(). Note this is not ideal as it take dependency on AutoMapper internals, but served my needs.

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>
    (this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        // This is not an ideal way to depend on internals of AutoMapper to find existing mapping to ignore the rest.
        //  Given the breaking change of AutoMapper since 11.0 and the amount of dependency we have on IgnoreAllNonExisting method
        // I chose to go with this approach. Longer term we may need to move to explicit mapping
        // using a type converter for each of IgnoreAllNonExisting() dependency
        var propInfo = expression
                        .GetType()
                        .GetProperty(
                            "MemberConfigurations",
                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var explicitMappings = (List<IPropertyMapConfiguration>)propInfo.GetValue(expression, null);

        var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var destinationProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties(flags);

        foreach (var property in destinationProperties)
        {
            if (explicitMappings != null && explicitMappings.Any(r => string.Compare(r.DestinationMember.Name, property.Name) == 0))
                continue;

            expression.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }

        return expression;
    }
}
```